# Pandas - Resampling and Interpolation with time float64

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample and interpolate a panda serie. However my index is in float64 like this :

```
       Value
Time        
0.0     0.00
0.0     0.00
0.0     0.00
0.0     0.00
0.0     0.00
0.1     0.00
0.2     0.00
0.3     0.00
0.4     0.00
0.5     0.00
0.6     0.00
0.7     0.00
0.8     0.00
0.9     0.00
1.0     0.00
```

This the beginning of my serie. 
I have to use something like this `upsampled = series.resample('D')` but I can't find the right letter instead of D and I have the following message :

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Float64Index'
```

I didn't succeed to change the float64. But it isstrage that there is no other way to interpolate only with time in float.
Thank you.

Comment: Time `0.0`, `0.1`.. is in `hours`?

Comment: in second sorry

Comment: Can you chage data sample with desired output?

Comment: I want to interpolate value with the time in ms for exemple. (the beginning is 0 but it changes after)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can convert floats [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then is possible use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) with some aggregate function like `sum` or `mean`:

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='ms')
df = df.resample('d')['Value'].sum()
```

---

```
df = df.resample('d')['Value'].mean()
```

Comment: is it possible to have NaN values where we added time value and then doing upsampled.interpolate(method='linear') ?

Comment: I think you need `NaN` values in `Value` column and then use `interpolate` for replace `NaN` to values.

Comment: in fact the resample didn't add new values and time but the format is now good

Answer (score 3):

The error you recieved tell yous that pandas wants a time-based index.  Resampling with pandas only works in a time-date format.  You could either, convert the floats into a time and date format, but that doens't seem appropriate in your example.  The other and (preferred) option would be to use something like scipy's `signal.resample` which takes in a numpy array:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html

Comment: Ok I am looking at it