# Upsample floating point second series in csv (with Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware that Pandas can do resampling, also for data that has timestamp indices which are floating point numbers: [Pandas - Resampling and Interpolation with time float64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047700/pandas-resampling-and-interpolation-with-time-float64)

However, I'm not sure how to apply that to my problem - my data has a timestamp column, which is a floating point number, with the meaning of seconds; this is `test.csv`:

```
Time[s], Channel 0
0.000000000000000, -0.736680805683136
0.000008000000000, -0.726485192775726
0.000016000000000, -0.721387386322021
0.000024000000000, -0.711191773414612
0.000032000000000, -0.700996160507202
0.000040000000000, -0.690800547599792
0.000048000000000, -0.670409321784973
0.000056000000000, -0.655115902423859
0.000064000000000, -0.629626870155334
0.000072000000000, -0.604137837886810
```

I can read this into pandas with the following `test.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os
import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(df_data)
```

This data was sampled at 125 KHz, which implies a sampling period of 1/125e3 = 8e-06, or 8 μs (and that is visible in the timestamps, as they are uniform).

Now, I would like to resample this to 500 kHz - that is, four times the rate - but, without linear interpolation; that is, every sample will merely be repeated at the new sampling period, 8/4= 2 μs; so I'd want an output like:

```
0.000000000000000, -0.736680805683136
0.000002000000000, -0.736680805683136
0.000004000000000, -0.736680805683136
0.000006000000000, -0.736680805683136
0.000008000000000, -0.726485192775726
...
```

Can I get this using pandas, and if so how? And to be more complete - how can I choose between "no interpolation" vs. "linear interpolation"?

Comment: You are looking for `resample` and then `ffill` or `bfill`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I found how to do this without interpolation, but am still not sure how to do it with interpolation.

Anyways, the solution code is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os
import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(df_data)
df_data.index = pd.to_timedelta(df_data.iloc[:,0], unit='s')
print(df_data)
df_resampled = df_data.resample('2us').pad()
print("-----")
print(df_resampled)
df_resampled['Time[s]'] = df_resampled.index.total_seconds()
print("--***--")
print(df_resampled)
```

So, the trick is this - first you need to add a "timedelta" index; note that the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047700/pandas-resampling-and-interpolation-with-time-float64) copies the original index (with `df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='ms')`); but here we already have timing data in column 0 - so we interpret that as seconds, and store it as "timedelta" index, using `df_data.index = pd.to_timedelta(df_data.iloc[:,0], unit='s')`.

Second tricky thing, is that `df_data.resample('2us')` actually returns a `TimedeltaIndexResampler [freq=<2 * Micros>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]`, and I couldn't figure out how to get tabular data out of it. But seemingly, as soon as you call the `.pad()` method on it, which the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) clarify with: "fill the NaN values using the pad method", then I get tabular data.

And finally, I have a timedelta index with the right timestamps, and data - but I still need to convert the timedelta index back to floating point seconds, which can be done with `df_resampled['Time[s]'] = df_resampled.index.total_seconds()`.

And the output of the script is:

```
$ python3 test.py
    Time[s]   Channel 0
0  0.000000   -0.736681
1  0.000008   -0.726485
2  0.000016   -0.721387
3  0.000024   -0.711192
4  0.000032   -0.700996
5  0.000040   -0.690801
6  0.000048   -0.670409
7  0.000056   -0.655116
8  0.000064   -0.629627
9  0.000072   -0.604138
                  Time[s]   Channel 0
Time[s]
00:00:00         0.000000   -0.736681
00:00:00.000008  0.000008   -0.726485
00:00:00.000016  0.000016   -0.721387
00:00:00.000024  0.000024   -0.711192
00:00:00.000032  0.000032   -0.700996
00:00:00.000040  0.000040   -0.690801
00:00:00.000048  0.000048   -0.670409
00:00:00.000056  0.000056   -0.655116
00:00:00.000064  0.000064   -0.629627
00:00:00.000072  0.000072   -0.604138
-----
                  Time[s]   Channel 0
Time[s]
00:00:00         0.000000   -0.736681
00:00:00.000002  0.000000   -0.736681
00:00:00.000004  0.000000   -0.736681
00:00:00.000006  0.000000   -0.736681
00:00:00.000008  0.000008   -0.726485
00:00:00.000010  0.000008   -0.726485
00:00:00.000012  0.000008   -0.726485
00:00:00.000014  0.000008   -0.726485
00:00:00.000016  0.000016   -0.721387
00:00:00.000018  0.000016   -0.721387
00:00:00.000020  0.000016   -0.721387
00:00:00.000022  0.000016   -0.721387
00:00:00.000024  0.000024   -0.711192
00:00:00.000026  0.000024   -0.711192
00:00:00.000028  0.000024   -0.711192
00:00:00.000030  0.000024   -0.711192
00:00:00.000032  0.000032   -0.700996
00:00:00.000034  0.000032   -0.700996
00:00:00.000036  0.000032   -0.700996
00:00:00.000038  0.000032   -0.700996
00:00:00.000040  0.000040   -0.690801
00:00:00.000042  0.000040   -0.690801
00:00:00.000044  0.000040   -0.690801
00:00:00.000046  0.000040   -0.690801
00:00:00.000048  0.000048   -0.670409
00:00:00.000050  0.000048   -0.670409
00:00:00.000052  0.000048   -0.670409
00:00:00.000054  0.000048   -0.670409
00:00:00.000056  0.000056   -0.655116
00:00:00.000058  0.000056   -0.655116
00:00:00.000060  0.000056   -0.655116
00:00:00.000062  0.000056   -0.655116
00:00:00.000064  0.000064   -0.629627
00:00:00.000066  0.000064   -0.629627
00:00:00.000068  0.000064   -0.629627
00:00:00.000070  0.000064   -0.629627
00:00:00.000072  0.000072   -0.604138
--***--
                  Time[s]   Channel 0
Time[s]
00:00:00         0.000000   -0.736681
00:00:00.000002  0.000002   -0.736681
00:00:00.000004  0.000004   -0.736681
00:00:00.000006  0.000006   -0.736681
00:00:00.000008  0.000008   -0.726485
00:00:00.000010  0.000010   -0.726485
00:00:00.000012  0.000012   -0.726485
00:00:00.000014  0.000014   -0.726485
00:00:00.000016  0.000016   -0.721387
00:00:00.000018  0.000018   -0.721387
00:00:00.000020  0.000020   -0.721387
00:00:00.000022  0.000022   -0.721387
00:00:00.000024  0.000024   -0.711192
00:00:00.000026  0.000026   -0.711192
00:00:00.000028  0.000028   -0.711192
00:00:00.000030  0.000030   -0.711192
00:00:00.000032  0.000032   -0.700996
00:00:00.000034  0.000034   -0.700996
00:00:00.000036  0.000036   -0.700996
00:00:00.000038  0.000038   -0.700996
00:00:00.000040  0.000040   -0.690801
00:00:00.000042  0.000042   -0.690801
00:00:00.000044  0.000044   -0.690801
00:00:00.000046  0.000046   -0.690801
00:00:00.000048  0.000048   -0.670409
00:00:00.000050  0.000050   -0.670409
00:00:00.000052  0.000052   -0.670409
00:00:00.000054  0.000054   -0.670409
00:00:00.000056  0.000056   -0.655116
00:00:00.000058  0.000058   -0.655116
00:00:00.000060  0.000060   -0.655116
00:00:00.000062  0.000062   -0.655116
00:00:00.000064  0.000064   -0.629627
00:00:00.000066  0.000066   -0.629627
00:00:00.000068  0.000068   -0.629627
00:00:00.000070  0.000070   -0.629627
00:00:00.000072  0.000072   -0.604138
```